Installing Ubuntu Core using the pre-built image on x86-64
I have been attempting to install the pre-built ubuntu core images on a small HP 260 G2 mini pc. I have tried using the amd64 builds for both 24 and 22 versions. I have followed the guide that Ubuntu has on their site (https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/install-with-dd). I'm getting to step 3 but not to any interactive part such as pressing keys to configure.
The system just seems to end up in an almost continuous reboot cycle. The Ubuntu site seems to say it will take a while to instantiate itself.
What is the usual ubuntu-core installation routine? And is what I could be seeing a normal part of the initial self-setup process of core?
Thanks

Please edit your question to clarify how many reboots, and whether or not your screen output is identical each time.
